CSS visibility and block doesn't work when I am trying to animation
So I make something very basic.
I want to make a button have a slide down feature using CSS. However it doesn't seem to work. In fact it seems like CSS maybe has removed it for everything except for the body.
h3 {
    display: none;
}

body:active h3 {
    display: block;
    opacity: 2;
}

<div class="subcontent"> <h3>words here</h3></div>

The thing is I don't feel the need to add the code for the button because no matter what I do it doesn't work. I can create a text using p and try to make it so that when you click on it or hover over it it would make the the div pop up. However it doesn't. Literally nothing works. I can put anything to replace body nothing seems to work. The only thing that seems to work is body. Which I find weird. Why isn't working? Literally it is so simple and I search online and people who are using visibility make it work and they don't even need bunch coding. Just add animations and all that. All I want is to make this work so I can add whatever I want to edit it. However it isn't working no matter what I replace it with. Why isn't it only working on body only?
Tried everything doesn't work. Only thing that works is using body. I tried doing it to just .subcontent but it didn't work so I added h3 to the words to see if that would do anything but it still didn't work.

display cannot be animated, it goes from none to block in a single step, these are not numbers that can be fractionned to create an animation/transition. Opacity can do for instance if it goes to/from 0 to any positive value. height, translate, can also be animated

Here you have it.


<style>
.subcontent {
    opacity: 0; /*instead of display: none*/
    transition: all 0.2s; /*by decreasing this number, the animation gets faster*/
    top: -20px; /*for the sliding motion*/
    position: relative;
}

h3:active + .subcontent {
    transition: all 0.2s;/*by decreasing this number, the animation gets faster*/
    opacity: 1;/*instead of display: block !important*/
    top: 0px;
}
</style>

<h3>Heading</h3>
<div class="subcontent">words here, words here, words here, words here, words here, words here, words here, words here, words here, words here, words here, words here  </div>



As @G-Cyrillus said, display cannot be animated.
I used opacity:0 instead of display: none;.
And I've added a top: -20 for a sliding motion.

quick questions does the item we are using have to be right next to it? LIke in your code, heading is just above words here. Does it have to be like directly above or directly under for it to work? Thanks

Yes, it has to be close to it, if it's far you'd need to use JavaScript to address it in the DOM.

You're welcome, my friend!

Also animation takes forever to load, is that normal? I would have to click on it like multiple times.

In that case, you can decrease the speed of the transition from 2s to something like 0.5s.

Hi are you available for another issue I am having?

@LoopyMomy sure. What's the issue? Post it as a new question, so others can tune in.



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        .subcontent h3 {
            max-height: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            transition: max-height 0.5s ease-out;
        }

        body:active .subcontent h3 {
            max-height: 100px; /* Adjust this value to the height of your content */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="subcontent">
        <h3>words here</h3>
    </div>
</body>
</html>



